# Odd issue with custom Excel VBA resetting values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm doing a few things at once which I believe may be causing issues. I've tested this VBA in Office 2013 and Office 2016 under Windows 10.

I have a multitude of worksheets, each of which is titled based on the month and year (ex: "November 2018", "December 2018", etc.). I'm using VBA to do two (separate) things:

1. Get the Active Worksheet's name
2. Traverse a previous worksheet's data

VBA Code:

```vb
Public Function RelSheet(iPos As Integer, zRange As String)

    'Relative Worksheet Reference Facility
    'eg: =RelSheet(-1,"A3") = Cell A3 in Previous (Left) WSheet
    'eg: =RelSheet(1,"A3") = Cell A3 in Next (Right) WSheet
    'eg: "#Error" when reference does not exist
    'eg: Can do maths =RelSheet(1,"A3")*2

    Dim shtActive As Worksheet
    Application.Volatile True
    Set shtActive = Application.Caller.Worksheet
    On Error GoTo BadSheetReference
    RelSheet = Sheets(shtActive.Index + iPos).Range(zRange).Value

    GoTo ExitFunction

BadSheetReference:
    RelSheet = "#Error"

ExitFunction:
End Function

Function TabName()
  TabName = ActiveSheet.Name
End Function
```

In my worksheets, I'm tallying a summation month over month until a near year is created, then the tally begins again at 0 (or whatever value Jannuary contains). Cell C8 is the current month's value, cell C9 is the summation of the previous month's value (C9 of the previous worksheet) + the current worksheet cell's  value in C8. The formula for that cell (C9) is as follows:
`==IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("January", TabName())), C8, RelSheet(-1, "C9")+C8)`

Unfortunately, once a worksheet name *does* contain the text of "January", all previous worksheets are also reverted to a sum of 0. I believe it is related to the RelSheet function and essentially recursively checking itself, but when I step through the code logically on paper, I don't see how it's doing this. My current workaround is just to manually set the value of the particular cell in a January worksheet to 0, and continue the formula on successive spreadsheets.

Comment: By default `Sheets()` will refer to the active workbook - do you have multiple workbooks open?  Also `TabName = ActiveSheet.Name` would probably be a problem on inactive sheets

Comment: `Sheets` is an enumerable, and there's no guarantee that the the index is ordered in any way what-so-ever. You'd be much better off iterating the `Worksheets` collection and checking the names.  What happens if the use re-orders the sheets?

Comment: @Comintern - are you sure?  I've never had a case where (eg) `Sheets(2)` didn't reference the second tab in the workbook (assuming there are at least two tabs and no hidden ones)

Comment: I only have the one workbook open. I'm not a VBA afficianado - these functions were cobbled together from various online searches, so it may be completely wrong and hazardous, but...not being a well-versed user is why I had to ask. :D

Comment: @TimWilliams I think what he means is that even though `Sheets(2)` references the second tab, there is no guarantee that the second tab will always be the same worksheet.

Comment: @TimWilliams No, but there is no requirement that it does. The more important consideration is that based on the OP's description, the order of the worksheets *isn't* the primary consideration - it's the month-year encapsulated in the names.

Comment: I did miss the question about what if the user re-orders the sheets, but I was mainly addressing the suggestion that the order of sheets in `Sheets` is not guaranteed, when we *know it is in this case* - it always matches the order of the sheet tabs in the workbook.  Maybe we're talking about two separate things here though.

Comment: @TimWilliams While we may both know that in *practice*, it's been drilled into my skull that a COM enumerator should not be assumed to be ordered unless it's documented for the OM. This probably says more about the state of the Excel OM documentation than anything...  But yes, I was primarily thinking of the external (naming) assumption.

Comment: Note "active sheet" is misleading here - it's not the `ActiveSheet`, it's whatever worksheet invoked the UDF: whether that sheet is "active" or not makes no difference. I'd suggest renaming `shtActive` to e.g. `callerSheet`, and the unqualified `Sheets` collection is, as Tim correctly warns above, implicitly referring to whatever the `ActiveWorkbook` is, which means the UDF will evaluate differently depending on whether the expected book is currently active or not. Use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` instead, to guarantee deterministic results.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Curiosity: Is there a deterministic difference between ThisWorkbook.Sheets and ThisWorkbook.Worksheets? (Nevermind, just found an example here: https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-worksheet/)

For the Sheets(2) reference conversation - if using Excel as an application with multiple users, this indeed would not be acceptable. In this case it's only for more efficient quick arithmetic and, as I'm the only user to access the file, yes - the order of tabs is maintained (or I have myself to blame and can fix it). Great points to bring up, though.

Comment: There isn't - but the `Sheets` collection contains non-worksheet sheets; use the `Worksheets` collection when you know you're getting a `Worksheet` object (as opposed to, say, a `Chart` sheet). The important part is the `ThisWorkbook` qualifier, without which what sheet you get depends on what workbook is currently active, or (in other contexts) even *where in the VBA project* the code is written: identical code written in a standard module may not behave the same way when written in a worksheet module, unless it's properly/explicitly qualified with a `Workbook` object reference.

Comment: Side note, you probably won't be the sole maintainer of that code forever: a common trope in programming... imagine the next maintainer is a violent axe murderer that knows where you live (code accordingly!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of suggestions:

```
Public Function RelSheet(iPos As Integer, zRange As String)

    'Relative Worksheet Reference Facility
    'eg: =RelSheet(-1,"A3") = Cell A3 in Previous (Left) WSheet
    'eg: =RelSheet(1,"A3") = Cell A3 in Next (Right) WSheet
    'eg: "#Error" when reference does not exist
    'eg: Can do maths =RelSheet(1,"A3")*2

    Dim shtActive As Worksheet
    Application.Volatile True
    Set shtActive = Application.Caller.Worksheet
    On Error GoTo BadSheetReference
    '##added workbook qualifier
    RelSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shtActive.Index + iPos).Range(zRange).Value

    GoTo ExitFunction

BadSheetReference:
    RelSheet = CVErr(xlErrRef)

ExitFunction:
End Function

Function TabName()
  '## not ActiveSheet
  TabName = Application.Caller.Parent.Name
End Function
```

Comment: Upvoted, although I'd warmly recommend returning `CVErr(xlErrRef)` (an actual `#REF!` worksheet error value) instead of a string that says `#Error` and that Excel doesn't understand as a worksheet error value. That would make the UDF work with `IFERROR` and `ISERROR` functions.

Comment: I would also suggest `shtActive.Parent` rather than `ThisWorkbook` to make it a bit more general.  And changing the variable name to avoid the missleading inference it's working on the Active Sheet (eg `shCaller`)

Comment: Brilliant. Wish I knew/understood VBA's object hierarchy a bit better to have known my stumbling blocks. I'll have to read up on the difference between Sheets and ThisWorkbook.Sheets, as well as ActiveSheet vs Application.Caller.Parent. Thank you so much for your expertise here (everyone!)!

Comment: Just realized when I wrote those functions oh-so-long ago, I had already looked up and used Application.Caller...dang. Just proves you lose it if you don't use it.